# How to animate a text that both slides and fades in using JavasScript and/or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have searched on google and here but not been able to implement any of the tips. I'm not good at JS at all. What I want to do is to have a single line of text fade in while it's floating upwards when you hover on a div and the reverse when you stop hovering.

I have not been able to use both the slide and fade effects.

Here is my code using JQuery 2.3.1

```js
$(function() {
  // DOM ready

  $('#card1').hover(
    function() {
      $('#artist1').slideDown();
    },
    function() {
      $('#artist1').slideUp();
    });

});
```

```css
#artist1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="card1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;">
  <h4 id="artist1" class="artistname ">testname</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: i've updated my answer below, it's working for me in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See changes to style and tags:

```js
$(function() {
  var slideDuration = 300;
  $('#card1').hover(
      function() {
        $('#artist1').stop(true, true)
          .fadeIn({ duration: slideDuration*3, queue: false })
          .css('display', 'none').slideDown(slideDuration);
      },
      function() {
        $('#artist1').stop(true, true)
          .fadeOut({ duration: slideDuration*1.5, queue: false })
          .slideUp(slideDuration*3);
      }
   )
});
```

```css
#artist1 {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="card1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>
<h4 id="artist1" class="artistname ">testname</h4>
```

Comment: Yes the code works, but I want to know how I can add a fade in and out effect on the text as well!

Comment: I can't see the fade in Chrome.

Comment: try now, you may need to experiment with fade in/out durations but this should get you close